# How do I encode the user input for an <input type= "text"> in razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-encode

I have the following input tag to implement an auto complete search:

```
 <input type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("QuickSearch", "User")" />
```

Will the user input be encoded automatically? And, if not, then how I can encode it?

Comment: to prevent from Active XSS attacks .......

Comment: You don't have any user input there; thus, there are no vulnerabilities.

Comment: In Active XSS attacks we can perform an attack without saving a user input.

Comment: You can only have an XSS attack if the attacker controls something.

Answer (score 2):

With Razor, by default all values are html encoded, unless you either explicitly use `Html.Raw`, or are using a custom implementation of `IHtmlString`.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the `HtmlHelper.Encode()` method to convert a value to an HTML-encoded string.

[MSDN Reference for `HtmlHelper.Encode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.encode%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your reply; but will all the input fields be encoded even if i am not using html helpers as in my case?